Is there a provision in grpc-java to add new services to grpc servers during runtime
I want to add and remove services to the grpc server without bringing down other services running.
Usecase:
Whenever I need to use grpcurl or grpcdebug for debugging purposes, these tools require like ProtoReflectionService, AdminInterface.getStandardServices and so on. If my server is already running with my critical services. How to add other services and also after adding new services will I be able to remove it without bringing down the critical services.
Due to some contraints I do not wish to add it along with critical services during first-time server bring up only in specific ocassions like during debugging I would like to add it and remove when purpose is over.

Depending on your constraints, there are two approaches:

Add the services up-front, but reject requests using an interceptor if not in "debug" mode. You can add this interceptor to just the debug services, so it doesn't impact others

Use serverBuilder.fallbackHandlerRegistry() with MutableHandlerRegistry


For the sake of example, let's say your current code looks like:
serverBuilder.addService(ProtobufReflectionService.newInstance());

Approach (1) could look like:
class DisableServiceInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  private volatile Status status;

  public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    Status status = this.status; // Take a snapshot of status
    if (status != null) {
      call.close(status, new Metadata());
      return new ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {};
    } else {
      return next.startCall(call, headers);
    }
  }
}

DisableServiceInterceptor disableDebuggingInterceptor =
    new DisableServiceInterceptor();
serverBuilder.addService(
    ServerInterceptors.intercept(
        ProtobufReflectionService.newInstance(),
        disableDebuggingInterceptor));

// To enable debugging:
disableDebuggingInterceptor.setStatus(null);
// To disable debugging:
disableDebuggingInterceptor.setStatus(
    Status.UNIMPLEMENTED.withDescription("debugging not enabled"));

Approach (2) could look like:
MutableHandlerRegistry registry = new MutableHandlerRegistry();
serverBuilder.fallbackHandlerRegistry(registry);

ServerServiceDefinition reflectionService =
    ProtobufReflectionService.newInstance()
// To enable debugging:
registry.addService(reflectionService);
// To disable debugging:
registry.removeService(reflectionService);

